# Change Android studio screen capture settings

Tags: android, android-studio, android-settings

Default Screen Capture Settings:
[image]

Settings I want to be displayed every time.
[image]

Whenever I capture the screen, I need to change the settings. Is there any way to change the default settings.

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable feature request if it doesn't exist

Comment: Right now it is not possible we will wait for these feature.